# Android Library Module using Architectural Components, without changing the main app module?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, androidx

I was thinking of migrating our legacy code to **Android Architectural Components**.
But, it's a huge project and it will take lots of time, with impact on business, if I plan to migrate all at once.

But, as it's a **Multi Module** project. I have some queries:

1. Can I change some modules to **Android Architectural Components** without
   affecting the main module ?
2. Is it possible to change some modules to **Android Architectural Components** using **Kotlin** ?

Need your suggestions.

Comment: I don't see any issues with either of those.  You could for example create a new feature module associated for example with particular screen and use AAC `ViewModel`/`'LiveData` etc with Kotlin with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both the question's answer is `yes`. [Android Architectural Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/)

1. `some modules to Android Architectural Components` you can use the component's in any module specifically without effecting any other module of your project example you can use `Live Data` only between few Fragment's of the module. similarly you can use `ViewModel` only in one Activity so Android Architectural Components is totally independent of the Module it can be used even only in a part of module also based on the need as i am using it in my project.
2. `some modules to Android Architectural Components using Kotlin` as 
   Android Architectural Components are supported both by Java and Kotlin so need to worry about that you can use it anyway Java or Kotlin